# I need the success swa to be shown when entering the password correctly

Tags: javascript, python, django, jinja2

js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    
        const botonGuardarCambios = document.getElementById('botonGuardarCambios');

        botonGuardarCambios.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const form = document.querySelector('form');
            const formData = new FormData(form);

            // Mostrar el componente cuando se carga la página
            const passwordHelpBlock = document.getElementById('passwordHelpBlock');
            passwordHelpBlock.classList.remove('d-none');

            // Borrar mensajes de error al recargar la página
            const formErrors = document.getElementById('form-errors');
            if (formErrors) {
                formErrors.classList.add('d-none');
            }
            const url = `/usuarios/cambiar_password`;
            console.log('antes del fetch')
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) {
                    
                    // Mostrar el Swal después de ocultar el componente
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Éxito',
                        text: 'Guardado correctamente', 
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1500
                    }).then(() => {
                        // Recargar la página solo si la contraseña se ha cambiado correctamente
                        location.reload();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Error al intentar cambiar la contraseña:',error);
                    Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'No se pudo cambiar la contraseña',
                });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error al intentar cambiar la contraseña:', error);
                    Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

views.py

```
def cambiar_contraseña(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
                
                return JsonResponse({
                    'success': True,
                })
            else:
                # Manejar errores en el formulario
                for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                    for error in errors:
                        messages.error(request, f"{field}: {error}")
        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error al intentar cambiar contraseña")
        print(e)
        
    return render(request, 'usuarios/cambiar_contraseña.html', {'form': form})
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('lista', views.usuarios_general, name='usuarios_general'),
    path('perfil', views.perfil_usuario, name='perfil_usuario'),
    path('cambiar_password', views.cambiar_contraseña, name='cambiar_password'),
    path('cambiar_password_full', views.cambiar_contraseña_full, name='cambiar_password_full'),
    

]
```

Problem
When I execute and save the password correctly, it always sends me succes:true on the screen, also in the js code it jumps directly to the catch message, that is, it does not enter the fetch. I want to show that json response so that when I save correctly, it sends the message of saving successfully and the screen refreshes, because currently it saves the new password entered but it is not receiving the json response correctly then it tells me the catch error message and sends me that success message on the screen how can I do it sort out
​